# Override .ToString method c#

Tags: c#

Okay, so I wrote this program from an exercise in a C# programming book (I'm trying to learn here) and it asks for "**Override the ToString() method to return all data members**".

Have I done this correctly? Or have I just successfully written code that compiles but does nothing? What is the purpose of **ToString**?

I have spent about 30 minutes looking at other posts on this and haven't figured it out, so I decided to make this.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication297
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String name = "Stormtrooper";
        Employee s = new Employee(name);
        Console.WriteLine("The type of hire is a {0}", s.Name);
        Console.WriteLine("The identification number is {0}", s.Number);
        Console.WriteLine("The date of hire is {0} ABY", s.Date);
        Console.WriteLine("The standard galactic salary is...{0:C}", s.Salary);

    }

    class Employee
    {
        private string _name;
        private string _number;
        private int _date;
        private int _salary;
        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return _name;
            }
        }

        public string Number
        {
            get
            {
                return _number;
            }
        }

        public int Date
        {
            get
            {
                return _date;
            }
        }
        public int Salary
        {
            get
            {
                return _salary;
            }
        }
        public Employee(string n)
        {
            _name = n;
            _number = "AA23TK421";
            _date = 4;
            _salary = 800;
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()

    {
        return "_name + _number + _date + _salary".ToString();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: So how do you understand the task? What do you think should be its result?

Comment: What is the result when you run this code?

Comment: And why would you bother overriding `.ToString()`?  (As a hint: what is the result of `Console.WriteLine("s = {0}", s)`?  Do you find that result useful?  What would make the result more useful?)

Comment: `return $"{_name}  {_number}  {_date} {_salary}";` should do.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You are returning a string that just says the phrase `_name + _number + _date + _salary`.

What you likely wanted to do is build a string using those fields. If you wanted them all mushed together [Concat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9c94ey1.aspx) would work, but it would be highly un-readable

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return String.Concat(_name, _number, _date, _salary);
}
```

However what would be better is to use [Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1csw23d.aspx) and include labels with the values

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return String.Format("Name:{0}, Number:{1}, Date:{2}, Salary:{3}",_name, _number, _date, _salary);
}
```

---

If you are using C# 6 or newer you can use the following cleaner format

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return $"Name:{_name}, Number:{_number}, Date:{_date}, Salary:{_salary}";
}
```

Which is the exact same logic as the previous `String.Format` version.

Answer (score 11):

The reason people override the `ToString()` method is to have a default string representation of your object, usually for display to the user or in a log or console, like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(yourClassObject);
```

If you do not override the `ToString()`, then its default implementation is to return the fully qualified name of your object, like this:

```
YourNamespace.YourClassName
```

By changing the inherited implementation (from `System.Object`), then you can make a nicer (read: prettier) representation, like this:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return String.Format("This instance of my object has the following: Name = {0}, Number = {1}, Date = {2}, Salary = ${3}", _name, _number, _date, _salary);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are using C# 6 (or later) use the `nameof()` method for the property names in the string in case the property names change. You can also use the `$""` notation instead of using `string.Format()`.

For example:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return $"{nameof(Name)}: {_name}";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather try something like

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return String.Format("Name : {0}, number {1}, date {2}, salary {3}",_name,_number,_date,_salary);
}
```

But it neads to be part of the class

so

```
class Employee
{
    private string _name;
    private string _number;
    private int _date;
    private int _salary;

    .....

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("Name : {0}, number {1}, date {2}, salary {3}",_name,_number,_date,_salary);
    }
}
```

Have a look at [String.Format Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx)

> Replaces each format item in a specified string with the text
>   equivalent of a corresponding object's value.

Comment: Or even probably `String.Format()`

Comment: @zerkms, just changed it to that. Will also include a link for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to format the output in a nice format. (not tested, though)

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return string.Format("Name: {0} Number: {1:n0} Date: {2:yyyy-MM-dd} Salary: {3:n2}", _name, _number, _date, _salary);
}
```

there are a lot of purposes overwriting .ToString(), depending on the context. for example,

- some developers like to have nicely formatted object description when doing debug, overwriting .ToString() would allow them to have meaningful description with some identifier (for example, the Id of a object);
- Some developers like to put some serialization code into the ToString() method;
- Some developers even put some debug code into the .ToString() method, though it might not be a good practice.

it really depending on the context of your needs. you may find some good practices to follow online - believe there are plenty of resources online.

Answer (score 0):

Without overiding ToString, if you tried to "get" the string value of an Employee, e.g.

`var employee1= new Employee();
Console.WriteLine(employee1);`

What you'd get is:

**ConsoleApplication1.Program+Employee**

Which provides no information at all to help you (or a UI) display relevant information.

I use 
`return _name + _number + _date + _salary;`
Which defaults to string,

or a more verbose

`return "Name:" + _name + " Number:" + _number + " etc...";`

Answer (score 0):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main( )
    {
        int Number = 10;
        Console.WriteLine(Number.ToString());

        Customer cc = new Customer();
        cc.FirstName = "Rakibuz";
        cc.LastName = "Sultan";

        Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(cc));

    }
}

public class Customer
{
    public string FirstName;
    public string LastName;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return FirstName + " " + LastName;
    }

}
```