# How to use a console application to execute methods from an api?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, console-application

I want to create a console application that can execute just a few of my methods from an API in order to make it easier for people to understand how these methods work. What is the best way to take a user input, and then display output data.

Here is what I have so far:

```
public class SampleProgram
{
    private readonly IRestClient _client;
    private const string vTruckUrl = "api/trucktype";

    public SampleProgram(string serviceUrl)
    {
        _client = new RestClient(serviceUrl);
    }

    public List<TruckType> GetVisionTruckType(string orderItemNumber) 
    //TruckType is a simple model containting two strings.
    {
        var request = new RestRequest(vTruckUrl, Method.GET)
        {
            RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json
        };

        request.AddParameter("orderItemNumber", orderItemNumber);

        var response = _client.Execute<List<VisionTruckType>>(request);
        if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            return response.Data;

        throw new Exception("The truck type and job name could not be queried.");
    }
}
```

Console:

```
public class ConsoleProgram
{

    private static SampleProgram _service = new SampleProgram("https://mytesturl.com/");
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("1" = GetVisionTruckType Method");
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("Select the number that correlates to the Method that you want to execute: ");

        string methodNumber = string.Empty;
        while (methodNumber == string.Empty)
        {

            methodNumber = Console.ReadLine();
            if (!(methodNumber == "1"))
            {
                methodNumber = string.Empty;
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid input.");
                Console.WriteLine("Select the number that correlates to the Method that you want to execute: ");
            }
            switch (methodNumber)
            {

                case "1":
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid order item number: ");
                    string num = Console.ReadLine();
                    var type = _service.GetVisionTruckType(num);
                    Console.WriteLine(type.ToString());
                    break;

            }
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
 }
```

My program is not outputting a list as I want it to. How do I fix this?

Comment: What exactly isn't working here?  What's your specific question?

Comment: @David currently my application returns "System.Collections.Generic.List". I want it to return actual data and I'm not sure how I need to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is incorrect:

```
var type = _service.GetVisionTruckType(num);
Console.WriteLine(type.ToString());
```

By default, `ToString()` will return the name of the type itself on reference types.  (After all, how would the system know for any arbitrary class what you *expect* the string representation of that class to be?)

You would need to print whatever it is you want to print from that `type` object.  (Which really should be called `types`, since it's a collection, by the way.  Bad naming adds to the confusion you're experiencing.)  For example:

```
var type = _service.GetVisionTruckType(num);
foreach (var obj in type)
    Console.WriteLine(obj.SomeProperty);
```

That would print the value of `SomeProperty` on each element in that collection.

Whatever you want to print is up to you.  The point is that C# isn't going to know what you want just by calling `ToString()`, you have to tell it explicitly.

---

Conversely, you could *override* `ToString()` on any class you control:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    // build and return what you want a string representation of this object to be
}
```

That would allow you to consistently call `ToString()` on objects of that type and get the string representation you expect.

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate over your items of the list that your method Returns.

```
switch (methodNumber)
{

    case "1":
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid order item number: ");
        string num = Console.ReadLine();
        List<TruckType> type = _service.GetVisionTruckType(num);
        foreach (var item in type )
        {   // this will only work if you override the ToString() 
            // method in the class TruckType 
            Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
        }
        break;
}
```

If you want to print only certain properties of `TruckType` you Need to Access them directly:

```
foreach (var item in type )
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.SomeProperty.ToString());
}
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18200427/override-tostring-method-c-sharp) is help to understand how ToString() can be overriden. It is actually nice to have if you want to display all Information about an object.