# How to pass data from class using a list

Tags: c#, console-application

```
namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class A
    {
        public int a = 100;
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
            A a = new A() ;
            list.Add(a);
            foreach (var i in list)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

this code gives the output:

```
ConsoleApplication3.A
```

How can I get the value from the class `A` without using `.a` and `this`? I want to continue to achieve this using `ArrayList`.

Comment: override `ToString`.

Comment: override `ToString()` in `a`

Comment: here is how: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173154.aspx

Comment: [here also](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18200427/override-tostring-method-c-sharp)

Comment: could you explain a little more in detail what you want to do with that value? Is it just for display in `Console.WriteLine`? Or do you really need the value as `int` itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override `ToString()` in class `A`.

```
public class A
{
    public int a = 100;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return a.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `.a` and `this` then for this purpose, you can use Reflection:

```
using System.Reflection;
...
```

and in you foreach loop:

```
FieldInfo[] fields = i.GetType().GetFields(); // All fields of the class A will be here.
foreach (var field in fields)
{
    // write out them all
    Console.WriteLine(field.GetValue(i));
}
```

Note:
I'm not sure what your final aim is, but I'm almost sure that there are lot easier ways to do that.

Comment: no i want to achieve this solution by the use of ArrayList

Comment: Just copy my code in your original foreach. It would still use your ArrayList.

Comment: i want to add that value in the list as you can see in my code i was trying to add in the list

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be what you are asking for:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class A
    {
        public int a = 100;
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var list = new ArrayList();
            A a = new A();
            list.Add((int)typeof(A).GetField("a").GetValue(a));
            foreach (var i in list)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```