# Linked List not printing with correct elements?

Tags: c#, linked-list, console-application, tostring

I was wondering how I could print out my linked list as it's currently showing the wrong text with the code I have written?

```
Dinosaur Dino1 = new Dinosaur();                           
Console.WriteLine("You have selected Create a New Dinosaur");
Console.WriteLine("Please enter Dinosaur ID ");
Dino1.ID = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Please enter Dinosaur Species");
Dino1.Name = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Please enter Dinosaur Diet Type");
Dino1.Type = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Please enter Dinosaur Period");
Dino1.Period = Console.ReadLine();
Dinolist.AddFirst(Dino1);
foreach (Dinosaur str in Dinolist)
{
    Console.WriteLine(str); 
}
```

This is what is being shown instead:

[image: ed]

Comment: You can override the ToString() in your Dinosaur class to display the properties you want.

Comment: @PmanAce `You can overwrite` -> `override` instead :)

Comment: Yes sorry, just woke up.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Override .ToString method c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18200427/override-tostring-method-c-sharp)

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ would it be '''  public override string ToString()
            {
                return base.ToString();
            }

Comment: @AhrenHart the return is wrong, you need to return what you would want. For example: `return Name + Type + Period` or however format you want.

Answer (score 3):

`Dinolist` is a list of a class (`Dinosaur` class) and is not a string, and using it Console.WriteLine, calls its `.ToString()` method that will be the result you are getting.

You can do:

Option 1:

```
foreach (Dinosaur dino in Dinolist)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Name: {dino.Name}, Type: {dino.Type}"); 
}
```

Option 2:
 just override the ToString() method of the Dinosaur class:

```
public class Dinosaur
{
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public string Type {get set;}
    //your class stuff here
    public override string ToString()
    {
         return $"Name: {Name}, Type: {Type}";
    }
}
```

Comment: `Dinolist is a list of a class (Dinolist class)` **no**, DinoList is a list of a class **(Dinosaur)**.

Comment: And that will work well with the linked list with it ?

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ you know that I have just made a mistake right? I just corrected it. Thanks for mentioning.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ you are welcome, you know I always spell Dinosaur incorrectly, that's why I copied and pasted, and copy & paste is evil, sometimes causes problems like this ;)

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani ha, it's not an issue :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to define the string representation of your class. Which can be achieved by overriding the ToString() method in your class definition.

**Remark 1:** ToString() method **is not** the method to display the properties. It just **generates string representation of the class**. Which means ToString() does not include any Console.WriteLine logic or something similar to this. Just create the string which represents the class, and return it.

**Remark 2:** After remark 1, The way you print should be like;

```
foreach (Dinosaur dinosaur in Dinolist)
{
     Console.WriteLine(dinosaur.ToString()); 
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: No need to actually call .ToString(), it will do it automatically.